# custom sort function behaves differently for string vs number keys

Tags: javascript, sorting

With help from various online sources I put together a custom sorting function.  It works properly when the object to be sorted has string keys.  However, it does not sort descending when the object keys are numeric.

```js
const sortObjectByKey = (obj, direction = 'asc') => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();
    if (direction == 'desc') keys.reverse();
    // return keys;
    const sortedObject = {};
    for (value of keys) {
        sortedObject[value] = obj[value];
    }
    return sortedObject;
}

const y = { 'zebra': 'runs', 'anteater': 'eats', 'kangaroo': 'hops', 'bovine': 'moos' };
console.log(sortObjectByKey(y));
console.log(sortObjectByKey(y, 'desc'));

const x = { 2021: 'twenty one', 2020: 'twenty', 2019: 'nineteen', 2023: 'twenty three', 2022: 'twenty two', 2018: 'eighteen' };
console.log(sortObjectByKey(x));
console.log(sortObjectByKey(x, 'desc'));
```

Why is descending sort not being honored when the object keys are numeric?

Comment: Just throwing this out there, Objects in JavaScript are unsorted. It may be logging in a sorted order, but that sort is not guaranteed. If you need a sort, you should be using an Array.

Comment: because Object doesn't use an Array structure.

Comment: the order is index like values/positive 32 bit integers are sorted first in order, then follows other numbers and strings in insertation order, followed by symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object traversal order is:

> The traversal order, as of modern ECMAScript specification, is
> well-defined and consistent across implementations. Within each
> component of the prototype chain, all non-negative integer keys (those
> that can be array indices) will be traversed first in ascending order
> by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of
> property creation

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Therefore, a custom ordering of numeric keys will not be respected during traversal.

```js
console.log({2:'two', 1:'one'})

// prints {1:'one', 2:'two'} instead of {2:'two', 1:'one'}
```